# Operator '>=' cannot be applied to types 'Duration' and 'number'.(2365)

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs, moment-timezone, luxon

I am getting this operator >= error in my vscode where I am unable to understand whats going on. I am trying to convert this code sample from moment into luxon but suddenly i am getting this error and my expected result is not coming true as I am getting in moment. My example code sample are given below, please take a look:

**This is moment example:**

```
const lastActivityLoaded1 = 1;

// moment().diff(lastActivityLoaded, 'hours') >= 48 && !canGetAllActivities()

console.log(`This keys moment Method : `, moment().diff('hours') >= 48); // false
console.log(
  `This keys moment Method 2 : `,
  moment().diff(lastActivityLoaded1, 'hours') >= 48
); // true
```

**This is luxon example:**

```
const lastActivityLoaded = 1;

console.log(
  `This keys luxon Method 2 :  `,
  luxon.DateTime.fromISO().diff({ hours: lastActivityLoaded }) >= 48
); // false
```

Here I am expecting true as output but I am getting false.

Here, when I hover my mouse pointer I am getting this error,

Operator '>=' cannot be applied to types 'Duration' and 'number'.(2365)
Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.(2554)
datetime.d.ts(635, 20): An argument for 'text' was not provided.
(method) DateTime.fromISO(text: string, opts?: luxon.DateTimeOptions): luxon.DateTime

**Here I am expecting true as output but I am getting false.**

Comment: Have a look at https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/moment. *"Moment's diff returns a count of milliseconds, but Luxon's returns a Duration. To replicate the Moment behavior, use dt1.diff(d2).milliseconds"*

Comment: Hello @Lennholm thank you for helping me, actually I try this ```console.log(
  `This keys luxon Method 2 ==== :  `,
  luxon.DateTime.now().diff({ hours: lastActivityLoaded }).milliseconds >= 48
);``` but still I am not getting the expected true result.

Comment: Argument of type '{ hours: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DateTime'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'hours' does not exist in type 'DateTime'. Did you mean to write 'hour'?(2345)
(property) hours: number

Comment: Here I am expecting to get true as output but I am getting still false

Answer (score 1):

See https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/moment for a guide on how to migrate from moment.js to Luxon.

Your first issue is with `DateTime.fromISO()`. The `fromISO` method expects a string as an argument. To replicate the functionality of calling `moment` without any arguments, use `DateTime.now()` instead.

Secondly, Luxon's `diff` method returns a `Duration` instance instead of a number like moment's does. To get the same functionality, get the milliseconds from the `Duration`. Also, the first argument to `diff` must be a `DateTime` instance, so you need to create one with the hours added and pass that.

```
luxon.DateTime.now().diff(
  luxon.DateTime.now().plus({ hours: lastActivityLoaded }), 
  'hours'
).milliseconds >= 48
```

Comment: But @Lenholm, here my output is coming false actually I am trying to make it true.

Comment: I had use this, ```console.log(`This keys luxon Method 2 ==== :  `,
  luxon.DateTime.now().diff(lastActivityLoaded, 'hours').milliseconds >= 48
);```

Comment: @GCT I overlooked some things about the `diff` method. Updated my answer.